# How might I transfer cookies and passwords from a broken laptop drive to a new laptop's browser?

Tags: firefox, ssd, data-recovery, file-management, data-transfer

My old laptop recently broke (in a way that can't be repaired). I salvaged the SSD card and turned it into an external drive so that I can get my old data off of it.

I mainly need all the data from my old browser: passwords, bookmarks, and cookies. Used firefox on both laptops, so I think it should just be a matter of transferring from the right file location on the SSD drive to the same file location on new laptop, but navigating the SSD drive is a nightmare and I don't know what file locations or files I should even be looking for. Any advice or answers?

Comment: You did not use a Firefox account?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Comment: Thank you. That's helped immensely